# Update kernel and not kill zfs - how?

Tags: server, kernel, zfs, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

So I have a server running a Ryzen 3 2200G, as of now I am running 4.18 kernel, I'd really want to go to 4.20.16 due to all the AMD updates.
But I am using zfs on the storage disks... last time I tried I killed the zfs installation and never got back to a fuctioning system again.
So anyone has blog post that describe how to do this?

Comment: You can see the version compatibility matrix for your version of ZFS here: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/releases.

Comment: As I understand it from that writeup is that my kernels are supported, and that is not the problem. If I update to newer kernel zfs will not start and says it is gone, if I run a whereis zfs the module is still in the old kernel. As of now I havent been able to reinstall zfs in any way. So for now I am stuck at 4.18.